# How to include the Perspective Toolbar in 'e4' .

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4, eclipse-emf, xmi

This [link](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/203790/) describes some mechanism to have the Perspective tool bar and mapping it to the ClassURI :

```
platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt/org.    eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.perspectiveswitcher.PerspectiveSwitcher
```

I tried the same but I didn't get any Toolbar contribution. I think I went wrong somewhere.. Can anyone please correct me if I went wrong anywhere ?

The code snippet which I used in "Application.e4xmi" file is :

```
<toolBarContributions xmi:id="_iJ5CQFxFEeWnG7SUWOY3vg" elementId="com.ami.veb.application.toolbarcontribution.0">
<children xsi:type="menu:ToolControl" xmi:id="_lvnLwFxFEeWnG7SUWOY3vg" elementId="com.ami.veb.application.toolcontrol.0" contributionURI="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.perspectiveswitcher.PerspectiveSwitcher"/>
  </toolBarContributions>
```

Comment: The existing Java and C/C++ perspectives use 3.x code and won't work in a pure e4 application.

Comment: Dear @greg-449 : Ohh.. :( :( Then it is not possible to switch to any of the Default perspectives  that Eclipse offers ? 
For Ex: 
'Open Perspective' dialog which eclipse offers to switch between different perspectives.

Comment: All the existing perspectives use 3.x code which won't work in a pure e4 app. The 'Open Perspective' dialog is also 3.x. Pure e4 is not suitable if you want to reuse existing 3.x code.

Comment: Thanks Greg for your information !

Comment: @greg-449: I've updated my question (to have the perspective look), Can you please take a look at it and suggest any ideas.   one link I had found (mentioned in the updated question) but unable to acheive what they've mentioned.

Comment: As it says in the link that code is in an `org.eclipse.ui.xxxx` plugin so it will not work in a pure e4 application since it requires the 3.x compatibility code.